# Factors of integers of the form $k^2-k+1$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quadratics, computational-mathematics

Factorisation of arbitrary integers is of course a computationally hard problem.

But what if the integers I'm interested in factorising are all of the form $k^2-k+1$ ?  Is there some way to compute the factors of such integers faster than using the general tools used for arbitrary integers (e.g whatever tricks SymPy's `factorint` throws at things)?

Obviously $k^2-k+1 = (k+\sqrt{k-1})(k-\sqrt{k-1})$ which for $k=10$ gets me the $7$ and $13$ factors of $91$ easily.  But for $k=256, k^2-k+1=65281$ it's no use at all and there's no obvious (to me) shortcut to the wanted $97$ & $673$.

Is there anything can be done?  I have a vague idea there ought to be *some* connection to quadratic Diophantine equations and thereby the Pell equation and continued fractions...

Comment: Well as an start, we have $(2k-1)^2+3=4x$, so $-3$ has to be a quadratic residue modulo any possible prime factor. (So we could precompute a short list of those primes)

Comment: Thanks; that does seem to ~halve the number of factors to test: in Sympy `print len(list(primerange(4,n))),len(filter(lambda p: is_quad_residue(-3,p),primerange(4,n)))` gets me `78496 39231` with n=1000000.  Which is nice but not a "big-O" improvment.

Comment: Outcome: I eventually managed to reformulate my overall problem so that it was only necessary to factor the expression for prime $k$, which reduces the computation needed massively.

Comment: Nice! What was the problem?

Comment: @chubakueno: it came up in a Project Euler problem I'm stuck on.  I don't want to identify which one specifically ('cos leaving hints around the net is just not the done thing).  And I haven't actually solved it yet (there are... complications), so the above might be a complete blind alley on some ideal solution.  Comments found around the web suggest it's one of the more computationally intensive problems though, and the prime k kind of fits the sub-minute rule even in Python, so maybe...

Comment: Hmmm... *you had my curiosity, but now you have my attention*. May you point me to the problem in chat? As I see it, anyone has posted an spoiler yet.

Comment: @chubakueno: See comment at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14049/room-for-travis-bemrose-and-chubakueno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bunyakovsky conjectured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) that any polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients that has the following properties takes infinitely many prime values:

1. The leading coefficient of $p(x)$ is positive.
2. $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.
3. The set of numbers $\{p(n)\,:\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ does not share a common factor greater than $1$.

It's easy to see that your polynomial satisfies all three of these constraints. But Bunyakovsky's conjecture is still just a conjecture: I think you'll have a hard time saying anything about prime factors of integers of the form $k^2-k+1$.